# How jasmine spyOn a generic method

Tags: typescript, generics, testing, jasmine, spyon

I try to make a spy on a generic method in typescript,
but cannot get Jasmine to recognise it.

---

I have code

```
http: HttpClient <- Not proper code, just showing type.
...
this.http.get<Customer[]>(url);
```

where I want to mock the `get<...>` method.

```
const httpMock = {} as HttpClient;
spyOn(httpMock, 'get')
   .and.returnValue(of({} as Customer[]));
```

But when I run the test I get

> Error:  : get() method does not exist
>   Usage: spyOn(, )

Comment: Try doing `const httpMock = { get: () => null } as HttpClient;` but you should be using the `HttpTestingController` (https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController) for testing HTTP.

Comment: Doesn't `HttpTestingController` solve the problem of making sure a call Has been made? - not that it mocks the answer from it?

Comment: You can also mock the responses with the flush method. https://medium.com/better-programming/testing-http-requests-in-angular-with-httpclienttestingmodule-3880ceac74cf Check that out.

Answer (score 0):

The remedy was to *not* use any generics when mocking.

```
describe('UserService', () => {
  it('should return proper users', (done) => {

    const returnedUsers = [...];

    const mock = {
      get: (_) => of({returnUsers}),
    } as HttpClient;

    const sut = new UserService(mock);

    //  Act.
    sut.getUser()
        .subsribe(users => {

            //  Assert.
            ...

            done();
        });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is some ugly code though. You need 10x more code to test a simple method. What if the method was not simple?

Comment: Then I would get another job.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I am aware of `HttpClientTestingModule`, but in simple cases it can be an overkill. If you properly mock `HttpClient`, for example, with `MockBuilder`, like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  return MockBuilder()
    .keep(YourService)
    .mock(HttpClient);
});
```

Then your code will work.

```
spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(of([] as Customer[]));
```

Notice you need `[]` instead of `{}`. However, it is usually a good idea to have a request object instead, which will have an array of items/row + other metadata. This is how most real-world API responses will come back.

If your app doesn't need any metadata, you can map to an array via pipe. But then it's flexible enough to change at any point.